# How to install an old kernel in Kali Linux 2022.4?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

The reason I want to install an old kernel is that my laptop WiFi adapter doesn't work well in monitor mode. By that I mean, airodump shows all clients as "not associated" when they actually are.

In the past, I managed to fix that by installing the kernel image 4.0.0-kali-686 pae, which worked well with the wifi driver (b43) for my wifi adapter (BCM4311), but it's been over 3 years now since I last used Linux and I don't remember how to do this.

The "not associated clients" problem has to do with either the wifi driver or with the kernel, but I don't know which one is to blame.
I installed the latest version of Kali Linux earlier today and just updated and upgraded it. If it helps, the "not associated" problem was encountered before and after the upgrade.

Comment: Probably not doable.  Stock kernel in Kali 2022.4 (in Kali now) is 5.16.0.  Try this article for recompiling the Kali kernel.    ....   https://www.kali.org/docs/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel/   Can you (better) upgrade the Wireless Adapter.

Comment: I managed to do it in the past in Kali Linux 2019 which by default came with a kernel version higher than 4.0.0. I did a lot of research back then and eventually installed the kernel version 4.0.0 alongside the stock version. Everytime I wanted to work with monitor mode enabled, I loaded the older version from Grub. It worked back then and should work now. @John

Comment: Try the article.  V2022.4 is a long way ahead of V2019 so I have my doubts.